# Nativescript Angular - Only white after splashscreen with Webpack for ios

Tags: ios, angular, webpack, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

after working on an app for quite a while all that's left now is improving startup timings - and the given solution for that is Webpack.
Using `npm run start-android-bundle` produces an app that works as intended (with some minor problems with firebase).

But using `npm run start-ios-bundle` produces an app that starts with the splash screen and then only shows white. Unlike other problems here on StackOverflow it doesn't just need a few seconds on the white screen but the starting component never shows up, **without throwing an error**.

Has anyone encountered the same problem or has an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: It is hard to say what may cause this behavior without the actual code base - contact me on the community slack channel (username: niki_iliev) if you can send sample project to debug

Comment: are you navigating to your home with clear history true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Nick Iliev for looking into the matter. The problem was in the Firebase-plugin and has been addressed here: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/564.

Updating nativescript-plugin-firebase should fix the problem